# Media screen in javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I say if my window width is like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){}
```

How can I include only `css` file for that and when it is higher to include other one?
Can this be done just in html or in javascript?

I don't want to  all css files. Just one by one on devices.

```
===========================================================================================
```

And while I ask this how to redirect phone or tablet to other link everytime they want to access big screen view website. Like when you attend facebook it redirect you to m.facebook.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need a mobile version if your design is responsive.
Here is an example HTML to include a CSS for a specific screen width:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 800px)">
```